# Using Map on a list of tuples and print it as flat string in Erlang

Tags: string, erlang, dictionary

I have a list of tuples:

```
X = [{"alpha","beta"},{"gamma","theta"}].
```

I want to print X as a flat string using, `io_lib:format("~s", [X])` in the following format:

```
[{"x":"alpha", "y":"beta"}, {"x":"gamma", "y":"theta"}]
```

How do I achieve this? I started using Map to do transform the list. But I was not able to print it as a string...(gave an unbound variable error on X).

Comment: If you could post/edit to add your code fragment that would be helpful - an unbound error on X implies that X does not have a value, and the difference between X and the "x":"alpha" bit is a bit of a mystery.

If you want to print X in "erlang" format, use the ~p directive, not ~s. ~s assumes that the parameter is a list of characters, not a list of tuples.

Answer (score 2):

Furiously looks like JSON serializing !
You should give a look into [rfc4627.erl](http://github.com/cstar/ibrowse/blob/05819b98d1799b386c6b5ffd99daf300bcbdcd3a/src/rfc4627.erl) as it does nearly exactly what you want.

Answer (score 2):

Enjoy neat trick:

```
1> X = [{"alpha","beta"},{"gamma","theta"}].
2> F = fun(X) -> [[$,|H]|T] = [[$,|["{\"x\":\"",A,"\", \"y\":\"",B,"\"}"]] || {A,B} <- X], [$[,[H|T],$]] end.
#Fun<erl_eval.6.111823515>
3> io:format("~s~n", [F(X)]).
[{"x":"alpha", "y":"beta"},{"x":"gamma", "y":"theta"}]
```

Notice all string operations which I do inside `F` are O(1).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
tuplelist_to_string(L) ->
    tuplelist_to_string(L,[]).

tuplelist_to_string([],Acc) ->
    lists:flatten(["[",
           string:join(lists:reverse(Acc),","),
           "]"]);
tuplelist_to_string([{X,Y}|Rest],Acc) ->
    S = ["{\"x\":\"",X,"\", \"y\":\"",Y,"\"}"],
    tuplelist_to_string(Rest,[S|Acc]).
```

Then:

```
1> X = [{"alpha","beta"},{"gamma","theta"}].
[{"alpha","beta"},{"gamma","theta"}]
2> io:format("~s~n",[test:tuplelist_to_string(X)]).
[{"x":"alpha", "y":"beta"},{"x":"gamma", "y":"theta"}]
ok
```

Answer (score 0):

You should just print it that way:

[{A,B},{G,T}] = X

io_lib:format("[{x:~s, y:~s}, {x:~s, y:~s}]", [A, B, G, T])